# Infimum of the inner product between the gradient of a least square loss and the direction

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A\in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$. The gradient of a least square loss ($f(x)=\frac{1}{2}\|Ax-b\|^2$) is $A^{\top}(Ax-b)$. Is it possible to find a $\delta>0$ for every given $\epsilon>0$ such that the following holds for any $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ when $x_0$ is given:
$$
\inf_{\|x-x_0\|\geq \epsilon} \frac{\langle x-x_0, A^{\top}(Ax-b) \rangle}{\|x-x_0\|^2 } \geq \delta
$$

**My try**

$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\langle x-x_0, A^{\top}(A(x-x_0+x_0)-b) \rangle}{\|x-x_0\|^2 } 
&=
\frac{\langle x-x_0, A^{\top}A(x-x_0) \rangle}{\|x-x_0\|^2 } 
+
\frac{\langle x-x_0, A^{\top}(Ax_0-b) \rangle}{\|x-x_0\|^2 }
\\
&\geq
\frac{\lambda_{\min}(A^{\top}A)\|x-x_0\|^2 }{\|x-x_0\|^2 }
+
\frac{\langle x-x_0, A^{\top}(Ax_0-b) \rangle}{\|x-x_0\|^2 } \\
&=
\lambda_{\min}(A^{\top}A)
\end{aligned}.
$$
Now there are two situations:

1. $A$ is full columns rank. Hence, $(\lambda_{\min}(A^{\top}A)>0)$. Then, how do I know $\frac{\langle x-x_0, A^{\top}(Ax_0-b) \rangle}{\|x-x_0\|^2 } > \lambda_{\min}(A^{\top}A) $?
2. $A$ is not full columns rank. Hence, $(\lambda_{\min}(A^{\top}A)=0)$. Then, how do I know $\frac{\langle x-x_0, A^{\top}(Ax_0-b) \rangle}{\|x-x_0\|^2 } > 0 $?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR; Such $\delta$ exists if and only if

1. $A$ is full column rank, i.e., $\lambda_{\min}(A^\top A) > 0$;
2. $A^\top(Ax_0 - b) = 0$.

---

This means $x_0$ is the optimal solution that minimizes loss, and the Hessian of the loss function is positive definite. Therefore, any movement from $x_0$ would induce a positive gain, which is the operational meaning of the statement you want to prove.

---

The sufficiency is easy to see.

Your attempt is also very close to proving the necessity. Let's start with the first line you wrote:

$$
h(x) \triangleq \frac{\langle x-x_0, A^{\top}(A(x-x_0+x_0)-b) \rangle}{\|x-x_0\|^2 } 
=
\underbrace{\frac{\langle x-x_0, A^{\top}A(x-x_0) \rangle}{\|x-x_0\|^2 } }_{h_1(x)}
+
\underbrace{\frac{\langle x-x_0, A^{\top}(Ax_0-b) \rangle}{\|x-x_0\|^2 }}_{h_2(x)}
.
$$

Let $\displaystyle x' = x_0 - \epsilon \cdot \frac{A^\top (A x_0 - b)}{\|A^\top (A x_0 - b)\|}$.
Then we have
$\displaystyle
h_2(x') = -\frac{1}{\epsilon} \cdot \|A^\top (A x_0 - b)\|.
$
Therefore, when take $x$ to be $x'$, we have  $\|x' - x_0\| = \epsilon$ and
$$ h(x') = h_1(x') + h_2(x') \leq \lambda_\max(A^\top A) -\frac{1}{\epsilon} \cdot \|A^\top (A x_0 - b)\|.$$

Then, if $A^\top(Ax_0 - b) \neq 0$, we can always pick a small $\epsilon$ such that $h(x') < 0$.

When $A^\top(Ax_0 - b) = 0$, we have
$h(x) = h_1(x) \geq \lambda_{\min}(A^\top A),$ and the equality can be achieved.

Hence, to ensure that a positive $\delta$ exists, we must have $\lambda_{\min}(A^\top A) > 0$.

Comment: what is TL;DR? by 1. and 2. do you mean both hold?

Comment: @Sepide. Yes, you need both 1 and 2.